OpenVPN scripts: `ifconfig_remote` is missing and no other variable contains the gateway's address
I'm trying to configure an OpenVPN client. I can't change the server's configuration. I'd like to set up the routes on my own (using the route-up and route-pre-down scripts), because I wish to use this VPN only for some traffic.
Normally OpenVPN exposes the $ifconfig_remote env var to the scripts, which I can use as the gateway. However that env var is not available with this server. I read online that this happens with topology subnet, which is indeed a flag that the server pushes.
These are all the environment variables the scripts see: config, tls_serial_hex_1, tls_serial_hex_0, tls_serial_hex_2, CLIENT_CERT, X509_0_CN, verb, daemon, ifconfig_remote, X509_1_O, X509_1_C, untrusted_port, dev, X509_2_C, X509_2_O, daemon_pid, tun_mtu, PWD, dev_type, untrusted_ip, daemon_log_redirect, remote_port_1, remote_port_3, remote_port_2, remote_port_5, remote_port_4, X509_1_CN, tls_serial_2, tls_serial_1, tls_serial_0, redirect_gateway, trusted_port, link_mtu, X509_2_OU, script_context, foreign_option_1, SHLVL, tls_digest_sha256_1, tls_digest_sha256_0, tls_digest_sha256_2, proto_3, proto_2, proto_1, proto_5, proto_4, tls_id_0, tls_id_1, tls_id_2, script_type, remote_3, remote_2, remote_1, remote_5, remote_4, common_name, ifconfig_local, daemon_start_time, trusted_ip, tls_digest_2, tls_digest_1, tls_digest_0, X509_2_CN, _.
None of them contains the gateway's IP address. ifconfig_remote, route_vpn_gateway or other variables useful to me don't even exist as shell/local variables.
This is the entire control message pushed by the server: PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,explicit-exit-notify,dhcp-option DNS 10.96.0.1,sndbuf 524288,rcvbuf 524288,tun-ipv6,route-gateway 10.96.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 60,socket-flags TCP_NODELAY,ifconfig 10.96.0.60 255.255.0.0,peer-id 786436,cipher AES-256-GCM.
I've tried to use pull-filter to ignore both redirect-gateway and topology, but the latter doesn't seem to get ignored.
How can I retrieve the gateway's IP address from the script called by that OpenVPN client, so that I can set up my custom network routes?
